# Arrow with closed head

Tags: wpf, geometry, shapes, drawing2d

I'm using an arrow control that I found on the net :

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2008/01/23/wpf-arrow-and-custom-shape.aspx

I've tried to change it to closed arrow like in the pic below w/o success.

[image]

Can anyone give an advise/help ?
I know its somethong with the **InternalDrawArrowGeometry** method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dammm .. I did it.

just added two lines in the end:

```
  context.LineTo(pt3, true, true);
  context.LineTo(pt2, true, true);
```

and set the FILL property of the Arrow.

:)